# Clear all Layers with vkCmdBeginRenderPass (Vulkan, Layered rendering)

Tags: graphics, vulkan

I have a framebuffer with one color attachment, which is a cube map with 6 layers. I try to use layered rendering with the geometry shader. Rendering of a simple triangle to all layers works. But I am not sure how to clear all layers with `vkCmdBeginRenderPass`.

`vkCmdBeginRenderPass` supports `pClearValues` and `clearValueCount` but I can not specify the number of layers. So only the first layer is cleared. Setting clearValueCount to 6 and giving 6 clear values also does not help.

I saw that `vkCmdClearAttachments` seems to allow to specify the layers.

Is `vkCmdClearAttachments` the only way, or did I miss something? Is there maybe a reason that  `vkCmdBeginRenderPass` only clears the first layer although rendering seems to render to all layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clearValueCount refers to the number of attachments to clear (with regards to their clearOp), not the layers of a framebuffer.

The number of layers to be cleared at the start of a renderpass (if clearOp is set to clear) for a framebuffer is specified via the layerCount of it's imageView's subresource.

Comment: The imageViews layerCount was actually correct. But VkFramebufferCreateInfo.layers was wrong (:. Interestingly Intel driver did still rasterize to the layers but not clear the layers. (which is what confused me) Nvidia driver did correctly neither render nor clear.

I guess that’s what you get from a low level API ;)